# FullCalendar Events Not Showing After 8pm in basicDay view

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

I came across a strange happening with using FullCalendar that I haven't been able to figure out. I'm not sure if it's a hiccup in FullCalendar or something I'm doing (probably the latter).

Events past 8:00pm aren't showing up on my calendar (i.e. an event at 8:00-9:00pm) in basicDay view. If I set the event start time to 7:59pm, it will show up. I've checked my timezones, and everything is set to Eastern Time (New York).

The other strange part to this is that the other views display correctly. Month and basicWeek display that dropped event just fine and have no issue with any events after 8:00pm.

See the page (and view the all code) here: http://www.clarksportscenter.com/calendar/. A good date to navigate to would be April 16 and look at the dark blue dates (Aquatics). Look specifically for an event named "Open Laps" that happens 8:00-9:00pm. It will be displayed in basicWeek by default, and you will be able to see it. If you click to turn the calendar into basicDay and move forward to April 16, the event disappears. Sometimes the event displays if you click backwards day by day or by clicking through the month/week/day views, sometimes it doesn't. The reason why this is problematic is that I also have the calendar on the homepage (http://www.clarksportscenter.com), and I can't have it dropping events on there.

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Right now I only see events with a 7:59 start time on all views.  Did you change something? Also, can you post the relevant Fullcalendar code. You can override most of the defaults and it sounds like that might be happening on one of your views.

Comment: Yes, I changed that particular event to 7:59pm and that made it show up. If it's set to 8:00pm it disappears, so that was a simple solution for now. I will post code soon. Thanks.

Comment: This is the code to set up my calendar:
`jQuery(document).ready(function() {
jQuery('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    
    header: {
      left: 'prev',
      center: 'title',
      right: 'next'
     },
     
    defaultView: 'basicDay',
    
    columnFormat: '',
    timeFormat: 'h:mm{-h:mm}',
    titleFormat: 'ddd., MMM. d',
    buttonText: {
      prev: '&laquo;',
      next: '&raquo;'
     },
     
    aspectRatio: 1.25,
    
    firstDay: 1,
    
    currentTimezone: 'America/New_York'
   
   });`

Comment: And this is the code to pull in the calendar info and set up the checkbox on/off: `var aquatics = jQuery.fullCalendar.gcalFeed("https://www.google.com/..."{ className: 'aquatics-events', backgroundColor: '#ffffff', textColor: '#3866b9', borderColor: '#ffffff' } );       jQuery('#calendar').fullCalendar('addEventSource', aquatics);
jQuery("#aquatics-check").click(function() {if (jQuery('#aquatics-check').is(':checked') == false) {jQuery('#calendar').fullCalendar('removeEventSource', aquatics);}
else {jQuery('#calendar').fullCalendar('addEventSource', aquatics);
}
});`

Comment: I'm pulling in 10 different calendar feeds, and each of them has this problem with events past 8:00pm. The currentTimezone option was only plugged in after I saw the issue come up (taking it out of the code doesn't fix the problem). Thanks for your help!

Comment: I guess there's a problem with calculating the start time in relation to your timezone, so your calendar request has the parameter `start-max : 2012-04-23T00:00:00Z` and your events the property `"startTime":"2012-04-18T17:00:00.000-04:00"`. This would explain why events with starttime >= 8:00 won't work, cause 8:00 (+4:00) would then start 0:00 the next day ?! .... hope my thoughts will help you at least a little bit ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I cannot reproduce your problem.

With a basic setup of fullcalendar all your events are shown correct, also without a specified timezone :

```
jQuery('#calendar').fullCalendar({
/************** Config ***************/
header: {
    left: 'prev,next today',
    center: 'title',
    right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
}
/************** Events ***************/
, eventSources: [
    { // gym
    url: "https://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/--YOUR_SWIM_EVENTS--group.calendar.google.com/public/basic"
    , className: "gym-event"
    // , currentTimezone: 'America/New_York'
    }
]
});
```

.... and a screenshot with your events : http://tinypic.com/r/lb1ia/5

Perhaps an update to fullcalendar 1.5.3 will do it ?